# Dynamically build data for ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I'm using "ExpandableListView" in my application to display some options that . I need a way to build automatically the information to show when a group is expanded as the information might be different each time the group is expanded.

Answer (score 1):

My guess, your items should be different ( different objects and use different layout ) so once you expand a group, the getView in your adapter will display layout needed. If you expect that data in your items themselves  changes and you need to update that - you need to notify your adapter ( notifyDataSetChanged ).

If you need something specific on group expended -  there are callbacks in the adapter -
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html
onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)

Comment: I use the same layout for a simple listView , it's indeed the data that's expected to change and many times at the moment of expantion is not even available and needs to be computed .

Comment: then AFTER you done computing, just notify the adapter that your data changed